# SQL - trying to exclude cohabitants from dedupe

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

*NEWBIE ALERT*

I have a SQL Server 2005 table containing customer accounts based on household, so each household has a `CustomerCode`, like so:

```
CUSTOMERCODE  UNIQUEID  TITLE  FORENAME  SURNAME   ADDRESS1
A3210         034123    Mr     Bill      Whithers  1 Roach Street
A3210         300443    Mrs    Jane      Whithers  1 Roach Street
A5342         450034    Mr     Jeff      Babbage   23 Ruben Road
A6786         258032    Mr     Aubrey    Truss     54 Bilge Terrace
```

When trying to de-dupe this table, we do not want to include any customers from the same household. I can find the dupes & so thought I could then wrap another query around that to exclude any rows that had the same `CustomerCode`, where the Title's don't match (I realise this is not a watertight method). But for the life of me I cannot get anything to work.

Any ideas out there? PLEASE. No doubt it's simple & I'm wasting your time, but as mentioned previously, I'm a bit of a newbie...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to exclude ALL households where there are 2 or more habitants or you want to only count them one time?

Comment: Yes exclude them ALL as they're not actually duplicates, just co-habitants. Many thanks! I realise the table design isn't great but we're stuck with that as it is & must work around it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only one row per household, then use `row_number()`:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by CustomerCode order by UniqueId) as seqnum
      from Customers c
     ) c
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you want households with only one member, then use `count() over`:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             count(*) over (partition by CustomerCode) as HouseholdCnt
      from Customers c
     ) c
where HouseholdCnt = 1;
```

These are both examples of "window" functions, which are very useful to learn about if you are learning SQL.

Comment: Many thanks Gordon - the latter might get me closer to what I want. But, ignoring that for a moment, how would I go about excluding all customers from the same household who do not have the same Title? Seems really easy in theory, but I can't put it into SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `row_number()` to assign increasing numbers to people that live at the same address.

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over (
                    partition by Address1
                    order by UniqueID) as rn
        ,       *
        from    YourTable
        ) SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1 -- Select only first person at an address
```

Comment: Excellent idea Andomar - I am using Over Partition to find the dupes in the first query. But the reason why I need to exclude further is that there may be dupe records of any of the customers at that address. Hence the rough idea of excluding if they have the same address, but different titles. But of course, even that is not perfect if a couple have a son who is a customer too, ie, two 'Mr' who are actually valid separate customers.

Comment: My initial query to spit out dupes:


`Select *, Row_Number() Over (Partition By CustomerCode, Branch Order By UniqueID desc) RowId  From CustomersTable`


'Branch' is just the code of the shop they visited - this is not unique to each customer or household.